# PIC18F67J90 Clock Selection

Tags: pic, frequency, oscillator, clock

I have two options to select system clock:

1. INTOSC
2. FOSC

I want to use the internal clock at 8/16 Mhz.

Which one should I select and what is the difference between FOSC and INTOSC?

Comment: Page 35 onwards [of the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39933d.pdf) describes the oscillator options.

Comment: This is a dumb [and lazy] question since it's directly and clearly answered in the datasheet.

Comment: @Olin I agree, but for a beginner a microcontroller's datasheet can be intimidating..

Comment: @m.Alin: Yes, but then they should ask about specific things they don't understand.  *Gimme da anser* questions, when the answer is in the datasheet are not appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you have more than two oscillator options..

> which one to select and what is the difference between FOSC and
>   INTOSC?

The first thing you need to do is to select which type of oscillator you want to be your main device oscillator ("primary oscillator"). You said you want to use the internal oscillator.

To do that we have to set some configuration bits at flash time. The bits that we're interested in are the **FOSC<2:0>** bits from the **CONFIG2L Configuration Register**:

> FOSC<2:0>: Oscillator Selection bits
>
> - 111 = ECPLL OSC1/OSC2 as primary; ECPLL oscillator with PLL enabled;    CLKO on RA6
> - 110 = EC OSC1/OSC2 as primary; external clock with FOSC/4 output
> - 101 = HSPLL OSC1/OSC2 as primary; high-speed crystal/resonator with    software PLL control
> - 100 = HS OSC1/OSC2 as primary; high-speed crystal/resonator
> - 011 = INTPLL1 internal oscillator block with software PLL control;    FOSC/4 output
> - 010 = INTIO1 internal oscillator block with FOSC/4 output on RA6 and    I/O on RA7
> - 001 = INTPLL2 internal oscillator block with software PLL control and    I/O on RA6 and RA7
> - **000 = INTIO2 internal oscillator block with I/O on RA6 and RA7**

So you need to set the FOSC<2:0> config bits to '000' to select the internal oscillator, with no PLL and no output of the clock to any external pins.

---

PIC18F67J90 has two internal oscillators, though:

- an internal oscillator block which provides an
  8 MHz clock (±2% accuracy): **INTOSC**
- an INTRC source (approximately 31 kHz, stable over temperature
  and VDD)

Obviously we want to select the faster oscillator (INTOSC). To do that we have to set the **INTSRC** bit from the **OSCTUNE** (Oscillator Tuning Register):

> INTSRC: Internal Oscillator Low-Frequency Source Select bit
>
> - 1 = 31.25 kHz device clock derived from 8 MHz INTOSC source    (divide-by-256 enabled)
> - 0 = 31 kHz device clock derived from the INTRC 31 kHz oscillator

So INTSRC = 1.

---

Next you'll need to set the speed of the internal oscillator.
For the Fast RC internal oscillator (INTOSC), the default clock speed is 4 MHz, but you can change it at runtime by modifying the **IRCF<2:0>** bits from the **OSCCON (Oscillator Control Register)**:

> IRCF<2:0>: INTOSC Source Frequency Select bits*
>
> - **111 = 8 MHz (INTOSC drives clock directly)**
> - 110 = 4 MHz (default)
> - 101 = 2 MHz
> - 100 = 1 MHz
> - 011 = 500 kHz
> - 010 = 250 kHz
> - 001 = 125 kHz
> - 000 = 31 kHz (from either INTOSC/256 or INTRC)
>
> *Modifying these bits will cause an immediate clock frequency
>   switch if the internal oscillator is providing the device clocks.

So you'll need to set the IRCF<2:0> bits to '111' if you want your internal oscillator to run at 8 MHz.

That should do it..

**Note1**: **Fosc** can also mean the frequency of the oscillator. Be aware that the system clock will be 4 times slower than provided Fosc (System clock = Fosc / 4). That means that if you select an oscillator of 8 MHz in frequency, the PIC will work at 2 MIPS. That's because, for a 8-bit PIC, it takes 4 clock cycles to execute one instruction.

**Note2**: As always, you'll find comprehensive information about this topic in the device's [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39933d.pdf).